# iOS Build Server Issue

Tags: codenameone

I'm facing an issue with Codename One Build Server
Since today, i can't build no more app with the new version of xcode
Everytime it throw me en error (specified here : https://s3.amazonaws.com/codenameone-build-response/822ca779-0d3e-4edd-8e53-adbdf2ff7dae-1473161307163-error.txt)
I've tried to generate a new certificate by Certificate Wizard but the problem remains.
For instance , i've set build target to iphone_old and it works but i would this problem be resolved until the 3.6 release :)
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The log expired by now but we discovered another problem with the xcode 7.x migration that might be relevant.

It seems that older versions of the google maps cn1lib triggered build errors. I suggest deleting the current cn1lib and the related `ios.*/android.*` build hints then reinstalling from the Codename One Settings extension manager.

If this isn't the case what cn1libs are you using?

Comment: I've make what you recommand but now, build failed too with another issue : /var/folders/p_/xlvwhg4101z8r81_nl13cds80000gn/T/build4192074624482223839xxx/dist/CalendoviaApp-src/CodenameOne_GLAppDelegate.m:38:9: fatal error: 'GoogleMaps.h' file not found
#import "GoogleMaps.h"

Comment: I think the GoogleMap plugin isn't complete when you install it by CodeName One Extension manager, even after a cn1lib refresh

Comment: Did you remove the ios.* build hints before the refresh libs? What are the values of the ios.* build hint?

Comment: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)                                               
Ios build hint :
ios.glappDelegate :  #import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h" 
ios.objC : true
ios.pods : ,GoogleMaps
ios.pods.platform : 7.0
ios.pods.source : ,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git

Comment: I have removed all ios.* build hints.

Comment: These look generally OK. But the build error doesn't make sense, notice that the glappDelegate references `"GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"` whereas your error referenced the old `"GoogleMaps.h"` path. Check the build error again, I'm guessing it's pointing at something different now.

Comment: I've removed all ios.* build hint, i've removed all lib/ios* and refreshed cn1libs. Now , there is another strange issue with build server : i have a lot of duplicate symbol like this ------> duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMSMapView in:
    /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4709155115117038349xxx/dist/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps
    /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4709155115117038349xxx/dist/CalendoviaApp-src/libGoogleMaps.a(GMSMapView.o) who provocate a build archive fail

Comment: Can you post a fresh build error link and any additional information about the project. Specifically I'm looking for: cn1libs used, build hints, target version etc.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i followed courses last week.  Now the build works anew, i've just deleted all files and folder in lib and refreshed CN1Lib 
Thanks for your support !